# Changing the size of only a single plot in matplotlib, without altering figure parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

Right now I have this code:

```
for each in list_of_cols:
    x = vary_k_df_rmse['k_value']
    y = vary_k_df_rmse[each]

    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.xlabel('k Value')
    plt.ylabel('rmse')
    plt.legend()
```

The above code produces the following graph, with multiple lines in a single plot:
[image: graph]

I need to enlarge the plot above so the legend isn't sitting on the lines.

Adding the following line doesn't work: plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)). This is what most existing answers suggest to do.

```
for each in list_of_cols:
    x = vary_k_df_rmse['k_value']
    y = vary_k_df_rmse[each]

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.xlabel('k Value')
    plt.ylabel('rmse')
    plt.legend()
```

[image: result]

Adding the above line to the for list that generates the graph made it so that the lines appeared in different subplots, rather than all on the same plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))` in front of the `for` loop so that only 1 figure is created.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

for each in list_of_cols:
    x = vary_k_df_rmse['k_value']
    y = vary_k_df_rmse[each]

    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.xlabel('k Value')
    plt.ylabel('rmse')
    plt.legend()
```